# How to get the value from the primary key AND foreign key when joining mySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have two tables, `employee` as the parent and `license` as the child. They both have a `Lic_ID` column for reference, this column is the `PK` in `license` and the `FK` in `employee`. The `license` table also has a column `Lic_Type` which holds the name of the license.

I am trying to create a table with list boxes so the `employee` table can be updated. The list box `value` needs to be populated with the `license.Lic_ID` and the `license.Lic_Type` is to be displayed in the `option`. Here is what I have:

```
(Employee name, Id, etc. called out up here)

<?php
echo "<select name=\"Lic\">";
echo "<option value=\"\">Select...</option>";

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT Lic_ID, Lic_Type FROM license");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
     {
     echo "<option value=\"" . $row['Lic_ID'] . "\">" . $row['Lic_Type'] . "</option>";
     }

echo "</select>";
?>
```

So that works good, it shows the license type and has the value set to the license id. What I want to do is have `<option selected="selected">` if the license id is set for an employee. This code doesn't work, but I think it illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php
echo "<select name=\"Lic\">";
echo "<option value=\"\">Select...</option>";

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT license.Lic_ID, license.Lic_Type, employee.Lic_ID FROM employee INNER JOIN license ON employee.Lic_ID = license.Lic_ID");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
     {
     echo "<option value=\"" . $row['license.Lic_ID'] . "\"";
         if($row['employee.Lic_ID'] = $row['license.Lic_ID']){echo "selected=\"selected\";}
     echo ">" . $row['license.Lic_Type'] . "</option>";
     }

echo "</select>";
?>
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: This looks like you're fetching all employees along with the license type to which each joins. Are you trying to do this for a single employee?

Comment: You should be using two queries, one to get the possible license options (which you have in the original code) and then one to select or iterate over the employee(s). You're trying to combine a specific record and all possible options in a way that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DavidHarkness I am trying to fetch it for all employees, not a single one.

Comment: @MattWhipple I agree it doesn't make sense. I realize this code is the wrong way to do it, I was really just trying to illustrate what I was trying to accomplish. If I use two separate queries, how would I run them both through the same loop? Also, why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may have been some confusion on what exactly I was trying to accomplish, I apologize for not being very clear. Anyways, I stumbled over the answer today, so I thought I should post it.

```
$sql1 = ("SELECT Emp_Name, Lic_MAT_ID FROM employee");

if(!$result_employee_query = $mysqli->query($sql1))
    {
    die ("There was an error getting the records from the employee table");
    }

while($employee = $result_employee_query->fetch_assoc())
    {
    echo "Employee Name: " . $employee['Emp_Name'] . "<br>";

    echo "License: ";
    echo "<select>";

    $sql2 = ("SELECT Lic_MAT_ID, Lic_MAT_Type FROM license_mat");

    if(!$result_license_query = $mysqli->query($sql2))
        {
        die ("There was an error getting the records from the license table");
        }

    while($license = $result_license_query->fetch_assoc())
        {
        echo "<option value=\"" . $license ['Lic_MAT_ID'] . "\"";
            if($license['Lic_MAT_ID'] == $employee['Lic_MAT_ID'])
                {
                echo " selected=\"selected\"";
                }
        echo ">" . $license ['Lic_MAT_Type'] . "</option>";
        }

    echo "</select><br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem: You want to see if the License has been added to ANY users or has it been unassigned. If any of the users have the license set then it's "selected", othervize not.

First you have to assign the keyword `"multiple"` to your `select` object to make it a listbox:

```
echo "<select name=\"Lic\" multiple=\"multiple\">";
```

Second: I would write this kind of query:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT l.Lic_ID, l.Lic_Type, e.cnt FROM licence l left outer join (select Lic_id, count(*) cnt from employee group by Lic_id) e on l.Lic_ID=e.Lic_id");
```

It selects the `Lic_ID`, `Lic_Type` and the `count` of how many employees have the respective Lic_ID set to it (`left outer join`)

and in the code just check, if the `count` is higher then 0

```
if($row['cnt'] > 0){ 
  echo "selected=\"selected\";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but I'm sorry, that's not what I'm after. I don't think it's possible to do what I want to do. I want to be able to display the records from the license table as options, but have them selected based on what's in the employee table.